# Building LocalMon sample in Windows XP

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, windows-xp, driver

I have a very basic question about the LocalMon print monitor found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

I have downloaded and installed the Windows Driver Development Kit and was trying to build the LocalMon print monitor sample.  The guide says "To build the sample, run build from the directory that contains the sample. After the sample is built, the sample will produce DDKLocalmon.dll."

I see a makefile in the directory.  However, do I need to install another program that will actually compile the code?

This sample source code does not have a project file, so it does not seem as though I can open the project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this in years, but Windows DDK usually comes with its own command-line C++ compiler (a slightly customized version of VC++). There should be some general build documentation somewhere in the DKK.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is run the CMD from the WDK install directory "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Driver Kits\WDK 7600.16385.1\Build Environments\Windows 7\x64 Free Build Environment"

then do cd to your src folders "C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src" 
then type BUILD and enter

you will notice the files will compile to another folder - you can install them from there

Instructions can be found here

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Driver Kits\WDK 7600.16385.1\Help\WDK Documentation